# Check whether data already exist or not

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to check either email, Identity card number or passport number has been registered before so, I use this query:

```
$qryc = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE login='".$this->input->post('email')."' 
        OR ic_number='".$this->input->post('ic_number')."' OR passport_number='".$this->input->post('passport_number')."'";
        $sqlc = mysql_query($qryc);
        $rsc = mysql_fetch_array($sqlc);
        $rowc = mysql_num_rows($sqlc);
        if($rowc > 0){

        redirect('registration/view_error/'.$rsc['user_id']);
        }else{
        $qryuser = "INSERT INTO users (login,password,user_type,ic_number,passport_number,user_application_status,verification_code)
                    VALUES ('".$email."',
                            '".$password_hashed."',
                            '2',
                            '".$ic_number."',
                            '".$passport_number."',
                            '0',
                            '".$verification_code."')";
        $sqluser = mysql_query($qryuser); 
        $userid = mysql_insert_id();
```

If the data already exist, it will bring error page to user. If not, there will be thank you page. The problem with my query is if the user never registered before, it still appear error page which tell them that the data already exist in database.

Otherwise, is there any other ways to check whether the data already exist in the database?

Comment: echo this variable $qryc and show it to us

Comment: 'SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE login='v@noemail.com' AND ic_number='232342' AND passport_number='' ' this is the query when i didn't fill out passport number field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking DB against `email` , `ic_number` or `passport_number` .
Is there possibility that one of the fields is empty? Then it can match with some DB row where it is also empty and you got records.
You should check values to empty before you compose your query.

You should change your query to look like this:

```
$icNumber = $this->input->post('ic_number');
$passportNumber = $this->input->post('passport_number');

$qryc = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE login='".$this->input->post('email')."'";

if ((isset($icNumber) && trim($icNumber) != ''))
{
$qryc .= " OR ic_number='".$icNumber."'";
}

if ((isset($passportNumber) && trim($passportNumber) != ''))
{
$qryc .= " OR passport_number='".$passportNumber."'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the field (email, Identity card number or passport number ) contains value, also you can try printing $rsc to see if there is any row is returned.

Comment: Forgot to tell you that field for IC Number and Passport is not required for both. it is either one, but cannot left blank for both

Comment: @bennybenito if just one value is blank, that's why you get results from DB